# How to get thumbnail of video file in android

Tags: android, file, video, preview

I have a video file in my sdcard. I would like to show a preview of this video in my ImageView . I know that there is a API:

```
ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoFile,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND)
```

but it always returns null, is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its working for me

```
 Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

> please check once, if you are passing path of video file .

Answer (score 0):

MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND and MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND are both integers with value 1

So try this first

```
Bitmap bmp = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(videoPath,1);
```